# Calling a component function outside of the component

Tags: aurelia

In Aurelia, say I have custom component named popup that has an `open` and `close` method on it. I can call those methods in the component, but how would I call them from outside the component?

app.html:

```
<template>
  <require from="popup"></require>

  Pop-up test
  <popup>
    <popup-body>
      <button click.trigger="close()">Close</button>
    </popup-body>
  </popup>
</template>
```

popup.html:

```
<template>
  <button click.trigger="open()">Open</button>
  <button click.trigger="close()">Close</button>

  <div class="popup" show.bind="visible">
    Pop-up!
    <content select="popup-body"></content>
  </div>
</template>
```

popup.js

```
export class Popup {
  constructor() {
    this.visible = false;
  }

  open() {
    this.visible = true;
  }

  close() {
    this.visible = false;
  }
}
```

Notice in app.html I'm adding a button to try to close the modal. Obviously `close()` won't work because it is looking for that method in app.js. How do I call the close method in popup.js?

Here is a [working Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/IFaJWyr5jepRfv70dWZ1?p=preview) of the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a hold of the view model of the component by using `view-model.ref`:

```
<popup view-model.ref="popup">
```

and then call close:

```
export class App {
  close(){
    popup.close();
  }
}
```

[here is the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dx3rXe4zReTawtOqaPTo?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I think I figured it out with `view-model.ref`

```
<template>
  <require from="popup"></require>

  Pop-up test
  <popup view-model.ref="popup">
    <popup-body>
      <button click.trigger="popup.close()">Close</button>
    </popup-body>
  </popup>
</template>
```